# In Liferay, from which folder does it pick up the CSS files for minification process?

Tags: css, liferay

I am finding old CSS code on my browser instead it has the new code in server files. I can see the minified CSS code on browser when application gets loaded up.
My team is using Liferay framework which seems to minify the CSS files. I am noob in liferay.

I found portal-ext.properties under liferay-portal-6.1.10-ee-ga1/tomcat-7.0.25/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/ but didn't found any parameter for minifying the CSS files?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't just update any CSS code you find deployed on the server. Instead, update your theme, build it (it builds to a web application) and deploy it to the server. This will take care of minification and updating caches. Just changing random files in the realm of the webserver will not.

For this you'll have to find the source files for your theme (or a whole plugins-sdk, which might contain that theme). Look at your organization's source control system, which is where I'd expect it.

Explaining how to update and build themes goes well beyond the scope of a single answer here, if these are really your first steps it might be worth getting some help from someone who has some experience with Liferay.